# Getting “MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms” with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, node-mongodb-native

I am getting the following error when I host my NodeJS Mongo code on AWS Lambda. I am using the node-mongodb-native library. I am using NodeJS with ExpressJS.

Below is my Mongo code:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

var client;

class MongoMethods {
    constructor(company, collection){
        this.company = company;
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    static async open() {
        if (client != undefined) return client
        client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb+srv://xyz:abc@redacted.mongodb.net/abc", {useUnifiedTopology: false})
        return client
    }

    async get(accessParameters){
        try{
            await MongoMethods.open()
            const db = client.db(this.company);
            const collection = db.collection(this.collection);
            const val = await collection.findOne({"_id":accessParameters["at"]});
            return val
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    async putIn(putParameters, type){
        try{
            await MongoMethods.open()
            const db = client.db(this.company);
            const collection = db.collection(this.collection);
            
            var existing = await collection.findOne({"_id":putParameters["at"]});

            if(type === "array"){
                var toAdd = existing !== undefined && putParameters["in"] in existing? existing[putParameters["in"]] : [];
                toAdd.push(putParameters["value"]);
            }else if(type === "dict"){
                var toAdd = existing !== undefined && putParameters["in"] in existing? existing[putParameters["in"]] : {};
                toAdd[putParameters["key"]] = putParameters["value"];
            }else{
                var toAdd = putParameters["value"];
            }
            
            await collection.updateOne({"_id":putParameters["at"]}, {"$set": {[putParameters["in"]]: toAdd}}, {upsert: true});
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}

module.exports.MongoMethods = MongoMethods;
```

Here is an except of the ExpressJS code:

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { validate, ValidationError } = require('express-superstruct');
const { MongoMethods } = require('./mongo.js')

MongoMethods.open()

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.route('/journey/')
  .get(validate({uid : "string", site : "string"}), function (req, res) {
    var args = req.query
    var mongoClient = new MongoMethods(args.site, "journeys")
    mongoClient.get({at : args.uid}).catch(console.dir).then(result => {
      if(result == undefined){
        res.status(404).json({"Database Error" : "UID does not exists or site is not a valid website"})
      }
      res.status(200).json(result)
    })
  })
  
var SETTING = ["status", "config"]
app.route('/internal/')
  .get(validate({site : "string", setting : "string", page : "string"}), function (req, res) {
    var args = req.query;
    var toSearchSetting = args.setting

    if(!SETTING.includes(toSearchSetting)){
      res.status(404).json(toSearchSetting + " can not be found in our database")
    }


    var mongoClient = new MongoMethods("xyz", "config")
    mongoClient.get({at : args.site}).catch(console.dir).then(result => {
      if(result == undefined){
        res.status(404).json("The contents you are serching for can not be found in our database")
      }else if(toSearchSetting == "config"){
        result["abc"] = result["abc"][args.page]
        res.status(200).json(result)
      }else if(toSearchSetting == "status"){
        res.status(200).json(result["status"])
      }else{
        res.status(404).json("An unknown error has occured")
      }
    })
  })
  
module.exports.handler = serverless(app)
```

I have looked for solutions online. The two I have seen solutions:

1: Whitelist IP address. I cannot do this as the code runs on AWS Lambda, we do not control the IP address.

2: Set “useUnifiedTopology” to “false”. I did that and that did not work either.

Could someone help with this please?

EDIT: Here is the error message:

```
2021-08-14T03:16:58.567Z    bbd37185-db36-4399-a842-903ba95aa2fd    ERROR    Unhandled Promise Rejection     {
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "MongoServerSelectionError",
        "errorMessage": "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms",
        "reason": {
            "type": "ReplicaSetNoPrimary",
            "servers": {},
            "stale": false,
            "compatible": true,
            "heartbeatFrequencyMS": 10000,
            "localThresholdMS": 15,
            "setName": "atlas-9r1p2o-shard-0"
        },
        "stack": [
            "MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms",
            "    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:325:38)",
            "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)",
            "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:375:28)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"
    ]
}

[ERROR] [1628911018568] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 400.
```

Comment: It appears you are using MongoDB Atlas.  Atlas requires you to provide a firewall rule allowing access.  As a test, you could allow all traffic (via IP address 0.0.0.0) but consider this as only a test - this is an unsafe mode for production use.  Perhaps AWS VPC peering would allow this connection in a safe manner.

Comment: @barrypicker I actually allow 0.0.0.0/0 in the settings. I do not hard code the IP. As per using a VPC, I have read that it negatively affects load times, which is not something I went.

As per the "unsafe mode for production", why do you think this is unsafe? Esp if it is running on AWS Lambda and on our account only. Just wondering.

Comment: Atlas allows/enforces ip address restrictions.  By default nobody is allowed to connect.  If you apply an IP address allowance for IP address 0.0.0.0 you are effectively turning off the firewall and allowing all hosts on the internet to attempt to connect to your database.  This is unsafe as there are (believe it or not) people who want to damage your database.  Best practice is to apply the minimum firewall access required to satisfy requirements.  In your case, allow the Lamda functions to talk to Atlas databases.

Comment: By the way, I just want to add - there are two places in MongoDB Atlas where firewall rules can affective interoperability.  The first is the database whitelist - which we discussed above.  The other is MongoDB Atlas API Key access, which we have not discussed.  If you have applied 0.0.0.0 to your Atlas API Keys this has no effect on your applications ability to connect to the database.  Your application will still require IP whitelisting at the database.

Comment: @barrypicker That makes sense. I don't use an API key, I use the URL to connect. Unless I am somehow? 

What you said definitely makes sense, though. I suppose since I already have 0.0.0.0/0, do you know what could be causing this issue? and how I could go about fixing it? 

Before my JS API, I used Python and I never had this issue.

Comment: As I understand it, you are wanting a NodeJS Lambda function to act against the MongoDB Atlas database.  You are comparing to a Python program.  I suspect the Python program was executed from your desktop, whereas the NodeJS Lambda is running on an AWS host.  BTW, I no longer see the actual error message.  Did was this post edited?

Comment: @barrypicker Sorry! Apparently the message did not add. Let me add it. 

Also, the Python program ran on AWS Lambda as well. My API used to be in Python before I moved to NodeJS. Both are on Lambda, not local.

Comment: @barrypicker I went ahead and added the error message.

Comment: It appears there remains a firewall restriction.  The Lambda function cannot reach the MongoDB Atlas database.  This is usually an indication the IP Address whitelist is not open for the client IP Address.  Please double check your Network Access in Atlas to allow the AWS Lambda client access.  BTW - I am not sure if AWS lambda hosts have dynamic IP addresses that can change, which would make this even more complicated if VPC peering is out of the question.

Comment: By the way - MongoDB Atlas supports Realm functions which are similar to AWS Lambda functions.  May want to invest some time looking at MongoDB Realm.

Comment: @barrypicker I will look into that. As per VPC peering, can that be done with for API Gateway + Lambda@Edge?

Comment: Also, why do you think the firewall is an issue if my IP address whitelist is set to 0.0.0.0/0. I have it set to that, so it should allow any and all IP address, no?

Comment: VPC Peering is a function of AWS.  If you have more than one VPC you can peer them together to allow private traffic between them.  MongoDB Atlas can be installed on AWS and if so, you can peer the MongoDB Atlas VPC with your own.  Of course, if you deploy MongoDB Atlas on Google Cloud Platform or Microsoft Azure you cannot peer with your AWS VPC.

Comment: @barrypicker I see, that makes sense. 
Also, why do you think the firewall is an issue if my IP address whitelist is set to 0.0.0.0/0. I have it set to that, so it should allow any and all IP address, no?

Comment: The error message you are receiving is stating it is timing out trying to establish a TCP socket connection.  Usually these are routing issues.  It could be that your AWS Lambda function is unable to reach outside the VPC.  If you believe Atlas is wide-open you may want to check your AWS security group rules to verify outbound routing is available.  Try to reach a different web resource (other than MongoDB Atlas) to verify you can reach out of the VPC.

Comment: @barrypicker We do not use a VPC so we have no security group rules. Additionally, the API works most of the times, just sometimes, it throws the error I posted above. I tested using Postman, and I get the error sometimes but usually, it works fine.